# Get BroadcastRecevier Object from ResloveInfo

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am stuck up just now; issue is my one of activity has register one private broadcastReceiver and I need to unregister it and as usual I cannot change that file.

My approach is get all broadcast receiver information () for that intent by Package Manager.queryBraodcastReceiver method.

Now I want to get broadcast receiver object from it.

Is there any other approach to work out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other approach to work out this problem?

Fix the activity to unregister its receiver. You cannot do this from anywhere else in your app.